Accessing one byte of a multi-byte volatile register
Suppose we have a pointer p, of type volatile int*. Assume that this is a currently valid pointer, i.e., reading from *p performs an implementation-defined operation, and is not UB.
What can happen if the program tries to evaluate something like *(volatile char*)p? Assume that int is 4 bytes, so this expression looks like "read the first byte of the int that p points to". At least, that's what it would do if that int were non-volatile. But in this case, it's volatile, so does that make it potentially UB?
For non-volatile ints, living in regular memory, executing a 1-byte load instruction might, on the hardware level, read all 4 bytes and then mask out 3 of them. But this is invisible to software, other than having possible performance implications. But I'm not sure if it's always possible for something like this to happen in the case of a 4-byte memory-mapped register. Are there any platforms on which executing a 1-byte load instruction of a memory-mapped register that is larger than 1 byte would cause a fault because the device simply doesn't support I/O in any size other than the size of the register?
The following question is related but the answers do not unambiguously address this issue: Using memcpy and friends with memory-mapped I/O

It will generate a byte access machine instruction. If your register allows byte access, it will work. If it doesn't, you will get your arch-specific exception. Once you do *(volatile char*)p - it "forgets" that p is a pointer to int (volatile or not) and is regarding it as a raw address (well, some language lawyer nit-picking be here) which is then casted to volatile char*

The details of how volatile objects work are implementation-dependant. All the standard really specifies is that the accesses won't be optimized away or reordered.

volatile has nothing to do with atomicity.

living in regular memory, executing a 1-byte load instruction migh Wait, we are mixing C language abstract machine with instructions. What should happen according to C and what should happen according to instructions generated by compiler are different sets. Also, you state that you have a pointer that is volatile. It doesn't state anything about the object. The object might be volatile or not.

You are asking two questions in one.

volatile only tells the compiler that the object is side effect prone. It means that the compiler can't assume that all changes are made by the visible code paths. So it reads the object from its storage location before any use and writes to it after any change. You can access any object (it does not matter if it is volatile or not) using pointer to char.




But I'm not sure if it's always possible for something like this to
happen in the case of a 4-byte memory-mapped register.

If the memory location is a memory-mapped register you need to access it the way described in your hardware manual (datasheet, reference manual etc). Some hardware does not accept different size accesses than for example 32bit. You have to access it as 32 bits. If you don't the hardware may not behave as expected (fault, reset, stall, incorrect data read/written etc etc).
The simplest method is to use temporary variable.
volatile uint32_t *reg1 = (volatile uint32_t *)REG1ADDRESS;

uint8_t read_byte(int byteno)
{
    uint32_t tmpreg = *reg1;
    uint8_t *reg8b = (uint8_t *)&tmpreg;
    return reg8b[byteno];
}

void write_modify_byte(uint8_t val, int byteno)
{
    uint32_t tmpreg = *reg1;
    uint8_t *reg8b = (uint8_t *)&tmpreg;
    reg8b[byteno] = val;
    *reg1 = tmpreg;
}


void write_byte(uint8_t val, int byteno)
{
    uint32_t tmpreg = 0;
    uint8_t *reg8b = (uint8_t *)&tmpreg;
    reg8b[byteno] = val;
    *reg1 = tmpreg;
}


I suppose the read-modify-write in write_byte could cause problems, especially if the register is write-only or has special semantics on write (e.g. set-1-to-clear).

If there are use-cases where only one byte needs to be modified out of 4-byte write-only register, the architecture should provide byte access instructions. Or the full value needs to be tracked in the software if possible (assuming the register value won't change as a result of some other side-effects).

In both examples you use reg8b first, and on the following line you use regb, without the 8. Is that a typo?

@IanAbbott the examples are only examples. If the register is write-only of course you will not read from it.

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica it is typo indeed
